# Azure SQL Database new created user with dbo schema but cannot search the tables under dbo schema

Tags: select, azure-sql-database, schema, ssms, dbo

In Master DB:

```
CREATE LOGIN Test_Admin   
    WITH PASSWORD = 'xxxx';  
GO  

CREATE USER Test_Admin
    FOR LOGIN Test_Admin
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [guest]; --want to grant minimum access rights
GO
```

In Target DB:

```
CREATE USER Test_Admin
    FOR LOGIN Test_Admin
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
GO
```

However, I could not search dbo's existing tables by below SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Why and how can I see back dbo's tables?

Comment: Did you give the Test_Admin the 'db_owner' permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a user in master DB,  and you want the user Test_Admin can access Target DB, am I right?

If you want to do this, you need to give database users "db_owner" permissions by joining the database role.

You can modify you code like this an try again:

In Master DB:

```
CREATE LOGIN Test_Admin   
    WITH PASSWORD = 'xxxx';  
GO  

CREATE USER Test_Admin
    FOR LOGIN Test_Admin
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [guest]; --want to grant minimum access rights
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'Test_Admin'
```

In Target DB:

```
CREATE USER Test_Admin
    FOR LOGIN Test_Admin
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'Test_Admin'
GO
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! How about if I don't want Test_Admin be a user in Master DB but only the DB admin in Target DB? (don't want Test_Admin to see other databases by execute below SQL: select * FROM sys.databases) . **If I don't create user Test_Admin in Master DB, I cannot use SSMS/MS Access to connect Target DB for querying**

Comment: @DaiKeung Maybe you can reference this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins). You can login your Target DB with ServerAdmin account with SSMS,  set the Target DB name you want to connect in Connection Properties.Maybe I can't answer all your questions, and thanks for accept my answer.